# Text format changing to date while reopening TSV file

Tags: excel, excel-2010

While updating and saving TSV file like **8-10** values to text format its working good. However, if I'm reopening the same file the **"8-10"** value format automatically changing to date **10-Aug**.

Why this is happening? Am i missing anything here?

Comment: Excel automatically formats everything that looks like a date to date format. The way around it is to change the fields to text, if possible. I always forget about it when importing any text files. If anyone knows a way to switch this off, I'd be very grateful.